# How to install Tenda W311MI WiFi Adapter on Fedora 36?

Tags: networking, fedora, wifi

My desktop machine is Fedora 36. I want to use the USB WiFi Tenda W311MI. I plugged this nano USB adapter and `lsusb` seems it:

```
uname -a
Linux mn 5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul 22 14:03:36 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 36 (Thirty Six)

[mn:~] lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (After Modeswitch)
...
```

But I cannot see wireless card on my Network control panel.

I tried to install driver for Linux, but Tenda has some mess with it. The last drivers I have found are:

```
DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913
```

so it seems old. I tried to compile it, but with no success:

```
[root@mn DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913]# make
make -C tools
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu '/home/mn/Pobrane/tenda/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/home/mn/Pobrane/tenda/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
/home/mn/Pobrane/tenda/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/mn/Pobrane/tenda/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/mn/Pobrane/tenda/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux modules
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu '/usr/src/kernels/5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64'
scripts/Makefile.build:458: uwaga: polecenia zakrywające dla obiektu 'modules.order'
Makefile:1439: uwaga: ignoruję stare polecenia dla obiektu 'modules.order'
  DESCEND objtool
make[3]: *** [Makefile:55: /usr/src/kernels/5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Błąd 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:69: objtool] Błąd 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1345: tools/objtool] Błąd 2
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/usr/src/kernels/5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:395: LINUX] Błąd 2
```

Do I need this driver (maybe newer version of Fedora wor)? How can I make my WiFi adapter to work with my Fedora machine?

Answer (score 1):

Based on `lsusb` output, this WiFi adapter uses a Realtek RTL8188GU chip.

This driver appears to support the chip, and has also been updated for the 5.18 kernel: https://github.com/McMCCRU/rtl8188gu

Use the `git` version control tool to download the driver source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/McMCCRU/rtl8188gu.git
```

After that, follow the instructions on the Github page to install it:

```
cd rtl8188gu
make
sudo make install
```

You will need to repeat these 3 steps every time you boot the system with a new kernel version.

If the WiFi adapter appears as a CD-ROM drive containing the Windows driver for itself, run `eject /dev/cdrom0` or `eject /dev/sr0` to get it into WiFi adapter mode. You will most likely have to do this every time you plug in/power up the adapter, so you may want to configure [`usb_modeswitch`](https://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) to do this step automatically for you.

`usb_modeswitch` should be already included in modern Fedora, or at least be available as a package in Fedora's standard package repository if you have chosen a minimal install. If it doesn't already handle your device automatically, you may need to add a configuration file to /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/ named `0bda:b711` (i.e. matching the USB vendor:product IDs of the device) with the following contents:

```
StandardEject=1
```

You'll also need to set up an udev rule to invoke `usb_modeswitch` when the WiFi adapter is detected. Your distribution should already have a lot of such rules at `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`: make a similar rule with the correct USB vendor and product IDs, and write your custom rule into `/etc/udev/rules.d/40-wifi-usb_modeswitch.rules` (it won't exist until you create it) so it won't get overwritten whenever the respective packages get updated.

Comment: w311miv6 seems to be using `aic8800` driver. Any idea which of the multiple source repos would most likely run on fedora 38/39? `ID a69c:88dc`, `iManufacturer           1 AICSemi`, `iProduct                2 AIC8800DC`, `iSerial                 3 20220127`